# Is there a way to provide implicit implementation of an interface from a 'child' interface?

Tags: c#, interface

I have an interface:

```cs
public interface IWeighted : IComparable<IWeighted> {
    int Weight { get; }
    // I know this part does not satisfy the contract from IComparable<>, also this 'throws' a warning about hiding an inherited member.
    public int CompareTo(IWeighted other) {
        return Weight.CompareTo(other.Weight);
    }

    // This satisfies the condition, but prevents an implementing class from being able to modify it or access it publicly.
    int IComparable<IWeighted>.CompareTo(IWeighted other) {
        return Weight.CompareTo(other.Weight);
    }

    // This part also does not satisfy the contract from IComparable<>
    public new int CompareTo(IWeighted other) {
        return Weight.CompareTo(other.Weight);
    }
}
```

and it 'implements/inherits' `IComparable<>` is there a way to provide a 'default' public implementation, such that it satisfies the contract from `IComparable<>`?

Example Usage:

```cs
public struct WeightedTest : IWeighted {
    private int m_Weight;
    public int Weight => m_Weight;


    /* SHOULD have existing implementation of CompareTo */
    /* I know that this next line is a compiler error, it's only to show intent */
    public int IComparable<IWeighted>.CompareTo(IWeighted other);
}

public struct WeightedTest2 : IWeighted {
    private RarityEnum m_Rarity;
    public int Weight => (LengthofRarityEnumValues) - (int)m_Rarity;

    /* SHOULD have existing implementation of CompareTo */
    /* I know that this next line is a compiler error, it's only to show intent */
    public int IComparable<IWeighted>.CompareTo(IWeighted other);
}

public class LootTable {
    private List<IWeighted> m_Items;

    /* other non IWeighted Related Code */

    public void Sort() {
        m_Items.Sort(); // This works thanks to IComparable
    }
}

public struct OtherIWeightedContainer : IComparable<OtherIWeightedContainer> {
    private WeightedTest m_Item; // for example
    /* other non WeightedTest related code */
    public int CompareTo(OtherIWeightedContainer other) {
        /* Higher Priority Conditions */
        return m_Item.CompareTo(other.m_Item); // This does not work.
    }
}
```

IComparable and IWeighted both properly expose the CompareTo Method, but in the event that a class Implementing IWeighted needs to be compared itself the compiler errors because no such method exists, unless I were to implement an identical method on each and every implementation of IWeighted.

Comment: Why do you need it? You can also think about how do you use it? Because I feel what you want is useless.

Comment: @shingo Why would being able to provide a default implementation of an interface be useless? I need it, because at some point an object that implements IWeighted may be needed in another class that implements IComparable<>, and as such would require a way to determine the 'greater/lesser' of 2 weighted items, without having to have every class implementing IWeighted from having to implement an identical method. In this exact situation the 'public access' is more important than the ability to 'override' it.

Comment: Sorry I can't image the situation well. Could you please add an example and explain why the 1st (or 3rd) `CompareTo` method can't work in the situation. It seems to me the another class that implements IComparable<> can call it without a problem.

Comment: I know the 1st or 3rd method doesn't implement the IComparable interface, so you need to explictly implement it as the 2nd form, it's not conflict to have both.

Comment: @shingo I've added the example and provided what I hope to be sufficient explanation.

Comment: Do you know that a class does not inherit members from its interfaces, if you want to access the method, the type need to be IWeighted, this is why I said it's useless. You can find the note here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods#concrete-methods-in-interfaces

Comment: I've only recently been able to work with 'default implementations' due to software restrictions, I had at the very least hoped that these default implementations could have been inherited. I otherwise was aware that classes and structs do not inherit members from it's interfaces

Comment: @shingo And thank you for the link, I've been attempting to find that information to no avail for a while now (I must have been looking up the wrong search terms).

Answer (score 0):

Following the discussion in the comments of my question I was able piece together some semblance of a solution

```cs
public interface IWeighted : IComparable<IWeighted> {
    int Weight { get; }

    // This method however does not satisfy the contract from IComparable
    public new int CompareTo(IWeighted other) {
        return Weight.CompareTo(other.Weight);
    }

    // This is to satisfy that contract
    int IComparable<IWeighted>.CompareTo(IWeighted other) {
        return CompareTo(other);
    }
}
```

and any implementation would simply need to include the line

```cs
public int CompareTo(IWeighted other) => (this as IWeighted).CompareTo(other);
```